# Emojis usage in Comments and Answers?

Tags: feature-request

Will Ask Different Community support Emoji in replies and answers?

Comment: [Pile of Poo] Hope so!

Comment: I hope not the sites are for exchanging information and are not for chit chat - as per the FAQ

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given that [emoji support is not uniform across all browsers](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/41228/why-do-emoji-like-%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BD-appear-when-i-use-safari-but-not-chrome/41347#41347) I would caution anyone attempting to use them in a question or answer to think carefully before doing so. Unless it adds a serious bit of relevant context to your question or answer, my advice would be to avoid them.

Sorry to ☔️ on your parade.

Comment: Chrome ✅/ Safari ✅

Comment: @JashJacob falls apart in tab bar title rendering though.